# React Native two drawers on one screen

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I have an app that needs to be able to use two drawer navigators, one on the left and on on the right side of the header.

I am at the point where I can get both drawers to open with the slide gesture, however I need to be able to open it programmatically. I have found the `navigation.openDrawer()` function only works with one of the drawers and not the other because it is only able to use one of the navigation props (whichever comes first) from my drawer navigators.

Below are my rendering functions:

```js
const LeftStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LeftDrawerStack
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
          <Icon style={{marginLeft: 10}} name='menu'/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    })
  }
);

const RightStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    RightDrawerStack
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerRight: (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
          <Icon style={{marginRight: 10}} name='ios-bulb'/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    })
  }
);

export const RouteStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: null
    }),
    LeftStack,
    RightStack
  }
);
```

and here are my drawer routes:

```js
export const LeftDrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Dashboard: {
      screen: DashboardScreen
    },
    History: {
      screen: HistoryScreen
    },
    Privacy: {
      screen: PrivacyPolicyScreen
    },
    TermsAndConditions: {
      screen: TermsAndConditionsScreen
    }
  }, {
    initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
    contentComponent: LeftDrawerScreen
  }
);

export const RightDrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    LeftDrawerStack,
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsScreen
    }
  }, {
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    contentComponent: RightDrawerScreen
  }
);
```

Here is a picture of what I have the navigation looking like so far, however both of the hamburger menus are opening up the same menu on the right instead of one menu on their respective sides.

[image: layout picture]

I may be missing some parts but I will be sure to post more info if I forgot any!

Comment: At User Experience (UX) level why do you need both drawers opened ? It would take the whole screen, why dont you use one drawer that takes the whole screen, and you can split up that drawer into two to show your options, but stil I dont have a picture of what you want to achieve

Comment: Here's how to do it in v5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742796/open-one-of-two-drawers-from-button-in-react-navigation-5/61745427#61745427

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to do this with the following setup (try to make changes to your structure to be like this):

```
const LeftDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
{
    LeftDrawer: MyStackNavigator,
},
    {
        getCustomActionCreators: (route, stateKey) => { return { toggleLeftDrawer: () => DrawerActions.toggleDrawer({ key: stateKey }) }; },
        drawerPosition: 'left',
        contentComponent: MyLeftDrawer
    }
);

const RightDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
{
    Drawer: LeftDrawer,
},
    {
        getCustomActionCreators: (route, stateKey) => { return { toggleRightDrawer: () => DrawerActions.toggleDrawer({ key: stateKey }) }; },
        drawerPosition: 'right',
        contentComponent: MyRightDrawer
    }
);

export const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    Login: Login,
    Home: RightDrawer
},
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Login',
        navigationOptions: { header: null, gesturesEnabled: false }
    }
);
```

The key is getCustomActionCreators. It allows you to call the function from any screen in `MyStackNavigator` like this: `this.props.navigation.toggleLeftDrawer();`.

Comment: getCustomActionCreators is not available in version 4.0.10. Is there another way or an equivalent to implement this problem?

Comment: @WaweruwaKamau Good question. I'm afraid I'm still using 3.x and I'm not sure about a new alternative, if I find out I'll update here

Comment: @WaweruwaKamau See if the answer below by Emerson Nascimento helps you, or alternatively, using "drawerToggleRoute" as shown [here] (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/780#issuecomment-370635948) and [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57647292/9173778).

Answer (score 1):

This is solution I do

Step 1: Create two drawer navigation and nest them together

Step 2: Store first drawer navigation in other place (Singleton)

```
// Drawer 1
import ContentLeftMenu from '@components/ContentLeftMenu';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import * as React from 'react';
import DrawerCart from './DrawerCart';
import { setNavigationDrawerHome } from './RootNavigation';
import { isTablet } from 'react-native-device-info';
import MainStack from './MainStack';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function DrawerHome() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="DrawerCart"
      drawerContent={() => <ContentLeftMenu />}
      screenOptions={({ navigation, route }) => {
        setNavigationDrawerHome(navigation)
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="DrawerCart" component={isTablet ? DrawerCart : MainStack} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

```
// Drawer 2
import CartScreen from '@features/cart/CartScreen';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import * as React from 'react';
import MainStack from './MainStack';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function DrawerCart(props) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="MainStackCart"
      drawerContent={() => <CartScreen />}
      drawerPosition='right'
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="MainStackCart" component={MainStack} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

```
// set navigation of drawer 1 with navigationDrawerHome
let navigationDrawerHome = null

export const setNavigationDrawerHome = (navigation) => {
  navigationDrawerHome = navigation
}

export const getNavigationDrawerHome = () => {
  return navigationDrawerHome
}
```

And when I use in Mainstack I when open Drawer 1 in left I use navigationDrawerHome, with drawer 2 just use navigation props

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MainStack() {
  const navigationDrawerHome = getNavigationDrawerHome()
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ navigation, route }) => ({
        headerLeft: () => <HeaderLeft />,
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      })}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="home_user_tab"
        component={HomeUserTabs}
        options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
          headerLeft: () => {
            return (
              <ButtonIcon
                onPress={() => navigationDrawerHome.openDrawer()}
                style={styles.buttonLeft}
                icon={images.ic_left_menu}
              />
            )
          },
          headerTitle: () => <LogoHeader />,
          headerRight: () => (<HeaderCardSearch
            navigation={navigation}
          />),
          // header: null
        })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

```
const HeaderCardSearch = (props) => {
  const { navigation } = props;
  return (
    <View style={styles.headerRight}>
      <ButtonIcon
        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
        style={styles.buttonCart}
        icon={images.ic_cart}
      />
      <ButtonIcon
        onPress={() => navigate('search')}
        style={styles.buttonSearch}
        icon={images.ic_search}
      />
    </View>
  )
};
```

Comment: hey Anh I'm afraid your solution is just too full of your own implementation details for me to extract the mechanism you are using. You refer to drawer 1/2 but they are not shown with those names.  And the real crux -  in HeaderCardSearch there is a reference to something called "navigate" for the 2nd ButtonIcon, what is it / where did it come from?  It would be great if you could edit out your implementation from this pattern as it looks like it could be really useful but I just can't pick out the approach.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to programmatically open both drawers this way:

```
// Opens left drawer
this.props.navigation.openDrawer();

// Opens right drawer
this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().dangerouslyGetParent().openDrawer();
```

And my navigation container looks like this:

```
static container = (): NavigationContainer => createDrawerNavigator({
    right: createDrawerNavigator({
        left: DeviceControlContainer
    }, {
        contentComponent: HistoryDrawerContainer,
        overlayColor: drawerOverlayColor()
    })
}, {
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    overlayColor: drawerOverlayColor(),
    navigationOptions: DeviceControlScreen.navigationOptions,
    contentComponent: DeviceControlDrawer
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! I'm pretty sure it's not the good way to do it, but I'm also sure that, after some research, react-navigation v4 doesn't manage that use case, aka open a specific drawer, so...

Answer (score 0):

Got inspired from Anh Devit solution, here is mine. I'm using a header bar across the app without a Stack Navigator, so had to go a slightly different route.

For my `RootNavigator`, I put my Header above my first drawer. I use `useState` so when I pass down the navigation objects as props, the `AppHeader` can re-render correctly when the Drawers have been initialized.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import LeftDrawer from "./LeftDrawer";
import AppHeader from "./AppHeader";

const RootNavigator = () => {
  const [navigationLeftDrawer, setNavigationLeftDrawer] = useState(null);
  const [navigationRightDrawer, setNavigationRightDrawer] = useState(null);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppHeader
        navigationLeftDrawer={navigationLeftDrawer}
        navigationRightDrawer={navigationRightDrawer}
      />
      <LeftDrawer
        navigationLeftDrawer={(navigation) =>
          setNavigationLeftDrawer(navigation)
        }
        navigationRightDrawer={(navigation) =>
          setNavigationRightDrawer(navigation)
        }
      />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default RootNavigator;
```

Here I'm creating my `LeftDrawer`, in which the `RightDrawer` will be nested. Notice setting the `navigationLeftDrawer` when the Drawer inits. Also, `navigationRightDrawer`has to be passed down as a param and not a prop.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItem,
} from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import RightDrawer from "./RightDrawer";

const LeftDrawer = ({ navigationLeftDrawer, navigationRightDrawer }) => {
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ navigation }) => {
        navigationLeftDrawer(navigation);
      }}
      drawerContent={(props) => {
        const { navigate } = props.navigation;
        return (<RightDrawerItems />)
        );
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="AccountDrawer"
        component={RightDrawer}
        initialParams={{ navigationRightDrawer }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );

export default LeftDrawer;
```

Likewise in `RightDrawer`, passing up `navigationRightDrawer` with the right navigation object.

```
import React from "react";

const RightDrawer = ({ route }) => {
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  const { navigationRightDrawer } = route.params;

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerPosition="right"
      screenOptions={({ navigation }) => {
        navigationRightDrawer(navigation);
      }}
      drawerContent={(props) => {
        const { navigate } = props.navigation;
        return ( <RightDrawerItems />);
      }}
    >
      {userAuth ? (
        <>
          <Drawer.Screen name={routes.dashboard} component={DashboardScreen} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <Drawer.Screen name={routes.home} component={HomeStack} />
      )}
      <Drawer.Screen name={routes.about} component={AboutScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name={routes.language} component={LanguageScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default RightDrawer;
```

Finally, the `AppHeader` :

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

const AppHeader = ({ navigationRightDrawer, navigationLeftDrawer }) => {

  if (navigationRightDrawer == null || navigationLeftDrawer == null)
    return null;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Icon
        name="menu"
        color={colors.white}
        onPress={() => {
          navigationRightDrawer.closeDrawer();
          navigationLeftDrawer.toggleDrawer();
        }}
      />
      {userAuth ? (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={() => {
            navigationLeftDrawer.closeDrawer();
            navigationRightDrawer.toggleDrawer();
          }}
        >
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{ uri: userProfile.profilePicture }}
          />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      ) : (
        <Icon
          name="person"
          color={colors.secondary}
          onPress={() => navigationLeftDrawer.navigate(routes.login)}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default AppHeader;
```

Comment: hey Hakim I tried to study your modified version of Anh's solution after failing to follow his, and unfortunately got just as confused as with his !  Your LeftDrawer component outputs <RightDrawerItems /> - which appears to be an error - and so does your RightDrawer component.  And either component imports the items.  You also destructure props to extract 'navigate'  once in each component, but never use it.  I'm hoping your pattern works but it looks like you've edited your code to remove your own implementation detail but left partial code which I worry isn't complete